# Create semi-cumulative columns based off several other columns. SAS

Tags: sas

I've got some data which is essentially lots of columns of information/data and dates and then two columns of numbers and a column which is a flag (ie its either a 1 or a 0). Each row is information on an individual at a particular month.

For the two columns of numbers I want to create two new columns which are the cumulative numbers for each individual over time. And for the flag I want it to be 1 for all future dates for that individual once it has first become 1 for that individual.

I'm struggling to word this (and so also to google what I want to do!) so I've put what I have and what I want below. In this example: A1, B1, C1 would be one individual and A1, B2, C3 would be another individual.

I've got this:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Date | Value_1 | Value_2 | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | 01Jan2021 | 0 | 100 | 0 |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | 01Feb2021 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | 01Mar2021 | 10 | 100 | 0 |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | 01Apr2021 | 50 | 0 | 0 |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | 01May2021 | 0 | 10 | 1 |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | 01Jun2021 | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | 01Jul2021 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A1 | B2 | C3 | 01Jan2021 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A1 | B2 | C3 | 01Feb2021 | 0 | 20 | 1 |
| A1 | B2 | C3 | 01Mar2021 | 10 | 20 | 0 |
| A1 | B2 | C3 | 01Apr2021 | 40 | 20 | 0 |
| A1 | B2 | C3 | 01May2021 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A1 | B2 | C3 | 01Jun2021 | 30 | 0 | 0 |
| A1 | B2 | C3 | 01Jul2021 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

And I want this:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Date | Value_1_full | Value_2_full | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | 01Jan2021 | 0 | 100 | 0 |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | 01Feb2021 | 0 | 100 | 0 |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | 01Mar2021 | 10 | 200 | 0 |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | 01Apr2021 | 60 | 200 | 0 |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | 01May2021 | 60 | 210 | 1 |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | 01Jun2021 | 70 | 210 | 1 |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | 01Jul2021 | 70 | 210 | 1 |
| A1 | B2 | C3 | 01Jan2021 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A1 | B2 | C3 | 01Feb2021 | 0 | 20 | 1 |
| A1 | B2 | C3 | 01Mar2021 | 10 | 40 | 1 |
| A1 | B2 | C3 | 01Apr2021 | 50 | 60 | 1 |
| A1 | B2 | C3 | 01May2021 | 50 | 60 | 1 |
| A1 | B2 | C3 | 01Jun2021 | 80 | 60 | 1 |
| A1 | B2 | C3 | 01Jul2021 | 80 | 60 | 1 |

I could do this if the only data I had was for a single individual, but there's lots of them. The code I've written is just giving me the total cumulative of the column - I can't figure out how to calculate them separately for each individual. I'm also struggling to write the code for the flag column for a similar reason. I've put the code below and would be very appreciative of any help/advice.

Note: I'm really new to SAS and to write this question I've struggled to get the date field in correctly by just typing out the data for this example (I've used this "Ignore" bit of the code below as a work around to get it into SAS) so if you could let me know what I've done wrong here that would also be greatly appreciated for the future!

```
data data_1;
input Col1 $ Col2 $ Col3 $ Date date8. Ignore Value_1 Value_2 Flag;
format Date date8.;
datalines;
A1 B1 C1 "'01Jan2021'd" 0 100 0
A1 B1 C1 "'01Feb2021'd" 0 0 0
A1 B1 C1 "'01Mar2021'd" 10 100 0
A1 B1 C1 "'01Apr2021'd" 50 0 0
A1 B1 C1 "'01May2021'd" 0 10 1
A1 B1 C1 "'01Jun2021'd" 10 0 0
A1 B1 C1 "'01Jul2021'd" 0 0 0
A1 B2 C3 "'01Jan2021'd" 0 0 0
A1 B2 C3 "'01Feb2021'd" 0 20 1
A1 B2 C3 "'01Mar2021'd" 10 20 0
A1 B2 C3 "'01Apr2021'd" 40 20 0
A1 B2 C3 "'01May2021'd" 0 0 0 
A1 B2 C3 "'01Jun2021'd" 30 0 0
A1 B2 C3 "'01Jul2021'd" 0 0 0
;
run;

Data data_2;
set data_1;
drop Ignore;
run;


proc sort data=data_2
    out=data_3;
    by Col1 Col2 Col3 Date;
run;


data data_4;
    set data_3;
    by Col1 Col2 Col3 Date;
 
    retain Col1 Col2 Col3 Date Value_1 Value_2 Flag Value_1_full Value_2_full;
 
    if first.Col1 AND first.Col2 AND first.Col3 AND first.Date then Value_1_full = Value_1;
    else Value_1_full = Value_1_full + Value_1;
run;
```

Comment: Just wanted to note that this is an excellent question - the data in hand and expected result were clearly shown, and the attempted code was also given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're pretty close!  I think this gets there...

```
proc sort data=data_1(drop=ignore)
    out=data_3;
    by Col1 Col2 Col3 Date;
run;


data data_4;
    set data_3;
    by Col1 Col2 Col3 Date;
 
    retain Col1 Col2 Col3 Date Value_1 Value_2 Flag Value_1_full Value_2_full;
 
    if first.Col3 then Value_1_full = Value_1;
    else Value_1_full = Value_1_full + Value_1;


    if first.col3 then flag=0;
    flag = max(flag,flag_Early);

run;
```

Only a few small changes.  I removed one pointless data step (The `drop` can be done in any of the other places you use the data) and change the `if first.` to be `if first.col3`.

You don't need `col2` and `col1` - `first.col3` is what you care about, the other two changing would also cause `first.col3` to also be true by default.

you also don't want `First.date` there - `first.date` is true EVERY TIME the date changes (or any other variable before it in the `by`), and that happens on every row, so it is *always* true!  You don't want that.

Finally, for `flag` you need to make a new variable.  Old variables are in fact *always* retained!  But they're also replaced every iteration with new values.  So we rename it to `flag_early` or whatever you like, and use the `max` function to assign a 1 to `flag` any time flag_early has a 1 *or* keep the 1 in flag if it has it from before - again resetting it every time `first.col3` is true.